# traceroute from one server to another in the same network works but not vice-versa

Tags: linux, iptables, firewalld, traceroute

I have two RHEL7.6 servers (s1, s2) connected in the same subnet. When I try **traceroute** from s1 to s2, it fails

```
s1$ traceroute s2
traceroute to s2 (s2_ip), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

 1  * * *
 2  * * *
```

But when I use *ICMP* instead of *UDP* for tracing hosts, then it works:

```
s1$ traceroute -I s2
traceroute to s2 (s2_ip), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  s2 (s2_ip)  0.464 ms  0.478 ms  0.484 ms
```

But when I do the same from s2 to s1, default works fine

```
s2$ traceroute s1
traceroute to s1 (s1_ip), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  s1 (s1_ip)  0.444 ms  0.457 ms  0.442 ms
```

I checked for any firewall rules blocking these UDP ports in both the servers, but firewall not enabled in both servers

```
s2$ firewall-cmd --list-all
FirewallD is not running

s2$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

However, I have tried doing these in the server s2, enabling all UDP **traceroute** ports

```
s2$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=33434–33534/udp
```

I also tried with the following iptables firewall rules:

```
#Outbound UDP traffic Policy
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 33434:33524 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --sport 33434:33524 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#Inbound ICMP traffic Policy
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 3/3 -d s2_ip -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 11  -d s2_ip -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Please note, the DNS in the server s1 is master

```
zone "some_name" in {
type master;
file "some_file";
};
```

And, DNS configuration in the server s2 is of type slave

```
zone "some_name" in {
type slave;
file "some_file";
masters { s1_IP; };
};
```

and name resolution (DNS lookup) works fine at both the servers

Comment: Check your ARP table make sure that these systems do not have identical MAC addresses.

Comment: The issue is resolved by disabling the security for that port on that particular node in Openstack by `openstack port set --no-security-group port_id` as openstack was not allowing UDP traffic on that port because of the security